# C# add scheduled task from XML

Tags: c#, xml, scheduled-tasks

I want to check if a scheduled task with the name /Mylibrary/Mytask and when it doesn't exist my program should add a scheduled task from an XML file.

My question: How can I check if a scheduled task exists and how can I add a scheduled task from an XML file? (in C#)

I can do this in the Windows Command Prompt with:
Check if the task exists: I dont know the exact command but i can check if it exists.
Add the task: schtasks /create /tn \Mylibrary\Mytask /xml C:\Path\To\file.xml

I want to use the Windows Task Scheduler and i already have an XML file for this.

Comment: Are you talking about a Windows Scheduled Task (at the operating system level) or is the scheduled task a feature of your program? Needs clearer explanation and an example of what you've attempted so far.

Comment: First create an xml file with the data needed for scheduled task like start time, name of executable, and how often task runs.  Does the scheduled task require any startup parameters?  Then ask the question on how to read xml file.

Comment: I already have the XML file with the parameters, startup information,... I just want to know how i can add a scheduled task from this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
    {
        ts.NewTaskFromFile("C:\\Path\\To\\file.xml");
    }
}
```

I think that will solve your problem.

BUT you have to import a NuGet Packet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/2.5.20), but thats quite easy. Just open the Package Manager Console and type: Install-Package TaskScheduler

Comment: Is it possible to pass in task credentials along with the XML file?

Comment: `NewTaskFromFile` returns `TaskDefention` but does not create a task. You need either `taskService.GetFolder("xxx").ImportTask(xmlFilePath)` or `taskService.GetFolder("xxx").RegisterTask(xml)` or `taskService.AddTask(relativeTaskPath, taskDefenition.Triggers.First(), taskDefenition.Actions.First());`